# The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll failed to load. The data is the error. When running my local website

Tags: asp.net, iis, event-viewer

I am getting this error when trying to run my code locally which is setup in IIS
[image]

I am not sure why this error happens or why it is looking for and aspnetcore dll when this is an old website that is running under .NET 4.7

I've installed the core runtime and restarted IIS and rebooted but still get the same error.  Also, I noticed that after the error happens, it shuts down the app pool associated with the website.

Any ideas welcome.  Thanks

Based on some comments, I am adding a screenshot of the event viewer details tab of the error highlighted in the first image
[image]

Comment: ASP.NET Core module once installed is on global level, so such errors are expected no matter what kind of web apps you are hosting. Switch to Details tab in Event Viewer and show us the error code please. Otherwise, nothing else is more helpful.

Comment: I provided a screenshot of the details tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you open VS to check whether ASP.NET Core is referenced in the `Applicationhost.config` file (`.vs\config\applicationhost.config`), and try to load non-existent modules.

If so, you need to comment out all references to aspnetcore.dll. Additionally, you need to do the same for the `Applicationhost.config` file in the folder `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config`. Then restart iis and try again.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not find that file in my config of the project, but I did find 2 files in the global config:
aspnetcore.dll
aspnetcorev2.dll

I commented them out and now I don't get the error, but I get a 500 error with no details in the Event Viewer. I assume this a separate issue.

What I don't understand is why these files are included globally if they are just going to cause this problem.

Comment: @JimboJones I commented the references in Applicationhost.config file and got same 500 error (500.19) with no details in Event viewer. Can u tell me how you handled this situation.

Comment: @ijs -Hello.  My fix for my situation was going into IIS manager and selecting the project. .  Then under the IIS section, there is a Modules icon.  I opened that and removed the references to the 2 dlls I mentioned.  Hope this helps